# Issue in helm command execution, helm show command doesn't work

Tags: kubernetes, command-line, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, zabbix

I am using below command to export default values of chart helm-zabbix to file $HOME/zabbix_values.yaml, as i am trying to install zabbix on kubernetes cluster.

```
helm show values cetic/zabbix > $HOME/zabbix_values.yaml
```

But, i am getting below error:

Error: unknown command "show" for "helm"
Run 'helm --help' for usage.
But helm --help doesn't show show in command list.
Do i need to install any helm plugin or suggest any other alternatives.

Comment: which version of helm you're using?

Comment: @KamolHasan Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.16.11", GitCommit:"73b28bab84490d18ab1b71489a574ee18e229eea", GitTreeState:"clean"}

Comment: can you check repo statuses or be certain that the repo is downloaded and usable ? If you can pull the repo or deploy it etc. If not, helm should show you a message as `hint: running "helm repo update" may help`

Comment: I have run  helm repo update , but still same issue.

Comment: Do you mean [`helm get values`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_get_values/)?

Comment: I tried helm get values also as below:                                                                                  
`helm get values cetic/zabbix > $HOME/zabbix_values.yaml`                                  

Error: invalid release name, must match regex ^(([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9_.]*)?[A-Za-z0-9])+$ and the length must not be longer than 53

Answer (score 2):

You should use ***inspect*** instead of ***show*** command as helm version 2 use ***inspect*** instead of ***show***.

Try using

```
helm inspect values cetic/zabbix
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do below to get values for a chart deployed -

```
helm get values cetic/zabbix -n <namespace>
```

Namespace is needed for helm 3

`helm show` is used to show the information on chart